# Class function not returning the correct value

Tags: python

I have this class:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s
    def getS(self):
        return self.s
```

I need to generate 5 instances of this class and only 1 instance will have a variable s with a value equal to true.

```
tests = [test(True) if i==sys.argv[1] else test(False) for i in range(5)]
```

Then I tried to print the values.

```
for i in tests:
    print i.getS()
```

Output is:

```
False
False
False
False
False
```

Shouldn't one of the value equals to True?

Comment: `sys.argv` is a list of strings, neither of its elements will ever be an integer. (Unless you manually modify it of course.) Try `if i == int(sys.argv[1])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it's a bit simpler. Also, use `xrange` if using Python 2.x, or `range` if using Python 3.x.

```
tests = [test(i == int(sys.argv[1])) for i in xrange(5)]
```

Your code is essentially correct - you just forgot to convert to `int` the command-line argument.